# How to transfer an argument in windows store app in MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, windows-store-apps

I'm starting in c# and windows 8 applications. The answer must be very simple but I can't do that.

I work in MVVM Light Model.

There is my code in page1.xaml.cs :

```
        private void ResultsGridView_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "test");
    }
```

But I can't override my function like in the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.Parameter as string;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    tb1.Text = "Hello, " + name;
}
}
```

Because it's in my MainViewModel.cs, not my MainPage.xaml.cs.

So, do you know a method to transfer the argument between this 2 frames?

Thank you for your help (and excuse my english).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I use Messenger, this is my page1.xaml.cs :

```
        private void ResultsGridView_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        selectAgence = selectAgences.Last();
        Messenger.Default.Send<Agence>(selectAgence, "1");

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

and this is my MainViewModel :

```
            Messenger.Default.Register<Agence>(this, "1", agence => { SelectAgence = agence; });
```

I hope this will help some persons.